# Getting start date of week from week number

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I have a list like this `lst = [25,26,27]`

numbers: `25`, `26`, `27` are the week number.

For each number from list I would like to have a start date, e.x. for week `25` the start date is `2022-06-21` (week starts on Monday).

Please, can someone help?

I have tried sth like

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
week = 25
year = 2021
date = datetime.date(year, 1, 1) + relativedelta(weeks=+week)
print(date)
```

but it doesn;t work.

Comment: Week 25 in 2021 starts on Monday 21st of June

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
lst = [25,26,27]
year = 2021

out = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(lst).astype(str)+str(year)+'Mon', format='%W%Y%a')
```

output:

```
0   2021-06-21
1   2021-06-28
2   2021-07-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

intermediate:

```
pd.Series(lst).astype(str)+str(year)+'Mon'

0    252021Mon
1    262021Mon
2    272021Mon
dtype: object
```

Comment: Tkanks a lot! Worked!